# Can I retrieve Published changes when changes have been Saved but not Published in Wordpress Semplice?

Tags: admin, editor

I have made changes to pages in the Wordpress Semplice theme and have saved them. However they are not published. The original content is still Published on the live site. 
Is it possible to retrieve the Published content back to work with in the page editor?
They appear to be permanently removed from the editing side. How is this possible if the Published is still displaying them?

Comment: What type of changes are you referring to? If you're editing theme files there's no such thing as published vs saved.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I'm referring to page changes made with the wysiwyg editor, not the theme files. I edited my question above.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, I'm not editing theme files - just content through the WYSIWYG. I can save and  it can remain unpublished albeit 'saved'. I want to revert the saved state back to what it was previous to changes saved - i.e. what it looks like 'published'. Apparently this is not possible and needs to be done through saving 'versions'.